# Why is this code returning an entity when the datastore viewer shows that NO entities of that kind exist?

Tags: python, entity-framework, google-app-engine, jinja2

I want to display a cart page that shows the items the user wants to buy. Before adding an item to the cart, I want to make sure that item has not been already added (as each item is singular and unique).

The way each item is modeled:

```
class SellModel(db.Model):
    user = db.ReferenceProperty(UserModel)
    amount = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    price = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    num = db.IntegerProperty(required = True)

    def render(self):
        return render_str("sellmodel.html", s = self)
```

The way each item displayed in the cart is modeled:

```
class CartModel(db.Model):
    user = db.ReferenceProperty(UserModel)
    num = db.IntegerProperty(required = True)
    def render(self):
        return render_str("cartmodel.html", c = self)
```

the code in the post method of the buy page where i check for item duplication includes

```
sells = SellModel.all().ancestor(sell_key()).order('price')
```

and

```
    #did user already put the same item (num) in cart? 
    item_check = CartModel.all().filter("email = ", email)
    item_check = item_check.filter("num = ", num)

    item_count = 0
    if item_check: #order already added to cart!
        self.write("ELLOHAY")
        item_count = 1

    if item_count == 0:
        cart = CartModel(parent = cart_key(), user = user, num = num)
        cart.put()

        numkey = SellModel.gql('where num = :num', num = num)
        derp = numkey.get()
        amount = derp.amount
        price = derp.price

        self.render('newbuy.html', first_name = first_name, amount = amount, price = price)  
    else: 
        cart_error = "this order is already in your cart"
        self.render("buy.html", cart_error = cart_error, sells = sells)
```

The problem: no CartModel entities exist yet. Zero. The datastore viewer doesn't even show the CartModel entity kind. Yet when I run this code, sure enough, "ELLOHAY" prints and the buy page is rendered with the error message that the user has already added the order to the cart? Why is item_check returning an entity when it shouldn't?

Answer (score 2):

This line of code is incorrect

```
if item_check: #
```

item_check is defined as

```
item_check = CartModel.all().filter("email = ", email)
item_check = item_check.filter("num = ", num)
```

At no point do you do a run(), fetch()  or get()
At the time of the comparison `if item_check`  item_check is a Query object and will evaluate to true. You need to actually run the query and examine the results - get() is probably a good start.

Also I see a number of other potential issues you will face with eventual consistancy but that isn't what you question is about.

Comment: thank you, that was helpful. also, are the all() query for CartModel and the gql query for SellModel the potential eventual consistency pitfalls you are talking about?

Comment: Yes.  Any query without an ancestor will have this potential.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this -

```
if item_check.exists():
    self.write("ELLOHAY")
    item_count = 1
```

This will not go inside the loop if item_check has no records.